# How can I get previous item in resultset?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Suppose we have this query:

```
ResultSet result = ("select * from table_name");
```

Now we can get information from result in this form

```
while(result.next())
{
  .
  .
  .
}
```

but in this form we can go forward. **Now I want to know if it possible that result get back?**

For example we get information `name='sam', fname='nic'`. And for next I want go back and get this information again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, JDBC supports that. You need to a **scrollable resultset**.

Something like this:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement(
   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
   ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from table_name");
```

Then you just use [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object `rs` to move within your results:

1. first
2. absolute
3. last
4. next
5. previous

Are methods that will help you navigate.

Comment: Do you know if the `previous`, `first`, `last` operations are fast, or internally they have to process full ResultSet before placing the cursor on the proper position? (so that they might work fast on relatively small set, but will start having performance issues on a set of thousands of elements)

Comment: @WallTearer it will depend on the drive implementation. But I would assume that they are fast and clever (won't transfer everything to client side until needed).

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Statement without passing parameters to it, it defaults to **ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY**.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

If you want to be able to scroll back you set the first parameter to either **ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE** or **ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE**. (Insensitive or sensitive in regard to changes to the database by others.)

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

**CONCUR_UPDATABLE** will allow you to update the ResultSet if you want, unless you do not need to, i which case you set it to **CONCUR_READ_ONLY**.

Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).